# Shader set to Alpha Blend - Possible to override this for output in "Normal" layer

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, transparency, unity

I might be going about this the wrong way, but here's the issue:

- I'm rendering a 3D model to animated sprites, including the normal layer (which I'll use for lighting).
- I've set up a shader, which creates a sort of glass ball effect and it looks just fine.
- Since the shader uses "Alpha Blend" as the "Blend Mode", absolutely nothing of that object renders to the the "Normal Layer" file output.
- Naturally, I still want it to render out the normal, which is based on my model’s geometry. I’ve set up a shader in Unity to read this information in order to light the diffuse sprite.

I feel like I should be able to direct blender to use a different shader for that layer. Am I thinking about this in the wrong way?

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain it clearly! My materials are all set in Unity and working fine. What I'm trying to do is streamline the process. Blender is exporting normals based on the geometry of my model, which I can use to light the 2D animated sprite. 

They're great apart from the fact that the normal layer file output is missing the head of my character, due to its shader. I just want to have more control over those render layers. Is that possible?

Comment: Sorry but however you interpret my intentions isn’t actually relevant to the question. I just want it to output something to the normal layer. I’ve made a small edit anyway.